# I want to write 'Đ'

Tags: symbols

I want to write only this word 'Đapić', but I don't want to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. What should I do?

I have tried With `\Dbar` but it's not working.

Comment: use Xe/LuaLaTeX on your Unicode file?

Comment: Can u please briefly explain ??

Comment: Which document class do you employ, and which fonts are used? What’s wrong with using the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`?

Comment: If I use fontenc it changes another alphabet also which I don't want.

Comment: if you do not change the encoding then you are saying that you want to use OT1 encoding that only has 127 characters per font and that character set does not include Đ.  Also unless you are writing English with no accented characters hyphenation will be incorrect unless you use an encoding other than OT1. Please provide a small test file that shows your problem.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[border = 3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\Dbar}{\stackinset{l}{0.1ex}{c}{}{\rule{0.33em}{0.3pt}}{D}}

\begin{document}

\Dbar
\scriptsize \Dbar

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's an emulation of Đ for the OT1 encoded Computer Modern font. Other fonts will need different parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[T1,OT1]{fontenc} % just for comparison

\DeclareTextCommand{\DJ}{OT1}{%
  \raisebox{-0.1ex}{\scalebox{0.75}[1.4]{--}}\kern-.4em D%
}

\begin{document}

\DJ api\'c (OT1)

\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
\DJ api\'c (T1)

\end{document}
```

The top line is typeset in the OT1 encoding, the bottom line is just for visual comparison.

[image]

Comment: This solution doesn't work with `\texttt{\DJ}` forexample.

Comment: @tomacs Of course it doesn't; but the OP doesn't want to use T1 fonts.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\DJ{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\char208}}
\begin{document}
\DJ api\'c
\texttt{\DJ api\'c}
\textsf{\DJ api\'c}
\end{document}
```

[image]